# ASP.NET MVC Multiple Radiobutton Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application which allows users to create their own surveys. For the sake of simplicity in answering this question, lets say that they can only create surveys with multiple-choice questions, each of which will be displayed to a survey-taker as a question followed by a list of radiobuttons representing each possible answer. Users can create as many multiple-choice questions in a survey as they want.

So, I have a ViewModel as follows:

```
public class SurveyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LabelText { get; set; }
}
```

Usually, I would just add a field for each question in the form to the `SurveyViewModel`. However, in this case I obviously don't know how many questions exist because the user can create however many they want - so I can't create a field to store the user's answer for each question.

So my question is: How can I write the ViewModel and the View (in Razor syntax) so that I can submit a form to a Controller, such that the responses to each of the arbitrary number of multiple-choice questions can be saved?

I have spent a long time banging my head against the wall on this one, so all help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I should clarify - we assume the questions have been created previously. I'm only interested in the bit where we display the question to a survey-taker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're asking because it seems you have everything you need, or at least most of what you need. In your view, you would just iterate over `Questions` on your view model, and then for each question, iterate over `Answers`. The only thing to bear in mind is that you need to use a `for` loop rather than `foreach` so you can index the list properties, allowing Razor to generate the right input names for the modelbinder. The one modification you need to make is to add a property like the following to `Question`:

```
public int SelectedAnswerId { get; set; }
```

Then, your view would look something like:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count(); i++)
{
    <p>@Model.Questions[i].Question</p>

    @for (var j = 0; j < Model.Questions[i].Answers.Count(); j++)
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Questions[i].SelectedAnswerId, Model.Questions[i].Answers[j].Id, new { id = "Question" + i.ToString() + "Answer" + j.ToString() })
        <label for="Question@(i)Answer@(j)">@Model.Questions[i].Answers[j].LabelText</label>
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Corrected radio button labels by passing an id for each each radio button and creating a label using that id. Otherwise, you'd end up with a bunch of labels that wouldn't actually activate the appropriate radio button.

Comment: Ah thanks that does the trick! The only thing is my question was a simplified version of what I'm actually doing... Because there might be other types of questions (e.g. one where you type the answer into a textbox) I'm having to cast each item in `Questions` to different subclasses of an abstract `Question` class. I can't figure out how you can get this to work with the casting?? Is it possible? I realise this is a horribly messy way of doing things but as hard as I've thought about it, I can't find a way to do this without all the casting. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I thought it worked, but it doesnt. When I get my form back in the Controller the Questions is null... Is there something else needed in that code?

Comment: Nope. That's all you should need. As long as `Questions` is properly indexed and at least one property on it is posted (in other words, you have a least one input on your page with a name like `Questions[0].Foo`), then `Questions` should not be null.

Comment: As for the different question types, you'll need to utilize a view model for your individual questions and condense it down into a least common denominator representation of a "question". You can't post back multiple different types of subclasses, because the modelbinder will not be able to differentiate.

Comment: OK, I got it to work - it was just the access modifiers on the setters for the ViewModel grr. Thanks for the help though!